# How to make span in bootstrap nav have width: 0px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bootstrap nav similar to this below

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="about"><i class="icon-info"></i><span class="no-width">About</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And for the .no-width class I set the css to

```
    .no-width {
        width: 0px;
    }
```

However, the span ends up having a width: auto? Why is this so? How can I make the span in the navbar have no width?

Here is what is what I see for the computed style when I inspect the span in chrome
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
a span.no-width {
    width: 0px !important;
    display:inline !important;   
}
```

Or this one

```
div.container ul.nav li a span.no-width {
    width: 0px !important;
    display:inline !important;   
}
```

**Update:**

Problem (question was not clear) was something else realized from the chat/comments and solution is :

**CSS:**

```
ul.nav li a span.no-width { 
    display: inline-block;
    width:0px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('span.no-width').animate({ 'display':'inline', 'width':'100px' },2000);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XAzF/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try more specificity in your css like:

```
.navbar .navbar-inner .container .nav span.no-width { width: 0px; }
```

or the not so favored:

```
span.no-width { width: 0px !important; }
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. I updated my question to show a pic of what I see.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do:

```
span.no-width {
    width:0;
}
```

Other wise it will call a div called no-width which doesn't exist

Comment: I still have the same problem. I updated my question to show a pic of what I see.